# laravel 5.5 - breaking subdomain pattern

Tags: php, laravel-5, wildcard-subdomain

I implement a subdomain system for user, which every user can go to their profile page like `user.example.com`.

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.example.com')->group(function () { 
    Route::get('/', 'ProfilesController@subDomain'); 
    });
```

Which `ProfilesController@subDomain` is a function that retrieve the data and redirect the page. However, user will always stuck in that url pattern no matter where he go.

For example, if `abc.example.com`, I want it to redirect to `example.com/profiles/abc`. But now I get `abc.example.com/profiles/abc`. And any link I go, it will stuck with `abc.example.com`.

How can I break that pattern after loading the profile page?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would do something like this with

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}'], function() { });
```

This would allow you to route to the domain of choice.